# mapping neo4j node to java class

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-data-neo4j-4

I have a  class called Disease. At sometimes A disease can be a symptom of another disease (Eg:- fever symptom of Dengue). I tried to map it using neo4j. I could map disease has symptoms but i couldn't map the above criteria properly in my node entity class.

This is the output, i need fever under dengue but now it show dengue under fever
[image: This is the output, i need fever under dengue but now it show dengue under fever]

Entity class which used to map disease
[image: Entity class which used to map disease]

Comment: Put your code in text, not in a screenshot.

Comment: Put your code in the question, not in a comment.